# How to get all the data from database in session after getting logged-in in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to display all the data of a user from db by using session.

```
<?php
class login_model extends CI_model
{
    function Can_login($email,$password)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('email',$email);
        $this->db->where('password',$password);
        $query = $this->db->get('registration');

        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: And what does this code has to do with your request? your question is unclear

Comment: i want to display all  the data from database. But i am not able to get this.

Comment: Based on the session, you mean user's ID that is stored in the session? what is the table's name and structure? what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You should return actual data from model function

```
<?php
function Can_login($email,$password)
{
     $query = $this->db
         ->where('email',$email)
         ->where('password', $password)
         ->get('registration');

   if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->result(); //or result_array() or other type
    }

    return false;
```

See documentation on [Generating Query Results](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#generating-query-results) for details on the types of returns available.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the way you are doing it above but with a few changes

```
<?php
class login_model extends CI_model
{
function Can_login($email,$password)
{
    $user = $this->db->select('*')
    ->where(['email'=>$email, 'password'=>$password])
    ->get('registration')->row();
    //dont need to check for row, if user is not found it will be empty and trigger false part of your statement
    //could even just return user in general and do this logic in controller
    if($user)
    {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
}
?>
```